# VIP topology on $X$

Tags: general-topology

I came across the following: Consider the VIP topology on $X$:

$$\tau=\{U \subset X: U=\emptyset \;\;\text{or}\;\;a \in U \}$$ where $a \in X$ is fixed.

The author proves every non empty open set is dense in $X$. After he proves every proper subset is nowhere dense.

How the second one is true ? because take any **proper non empty open set** $U$,  and using  first one, $U$ is dense. But by the second one $U$ is nowhere dense.  What's  going on? Is I'm misunderstand something or it is a typo in a book?

---

I add a reference to it: See **4** and **7**

[image]

---

Here's his proof:

[image]

[image]

Comment: *Any* subset, or any non-open subset (which incidentally means any closed proper subset in this topology)? What is the proof? Who is the author? Where is this from?

Comment: I add a reference. load this page to see...!

Comment: You say that this is possibly a "typo in a book". Which book? Did you check for errata?

Comment: Dense subsets cannot be nowhere dense. The closure is $X$ and thus so is the interior of the closure. That's a clear contradiction.

Comment: Perhaps the statement should be "every proper **closed** subset is nowhere dense" in duality to "every nonempty open subset is dense".

Comment: Hold on everyone! I add a proof too!

Comment: What book are you quoting from? Quoting without attribution is theft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof you post clearly shows that we assume that $\overline A$ is a proper subset of $X$, rather than just $A$ itself.

So yes, this is in fact a typo. In other words, the proof shows that if $A$ is not dense, then it is nowhere dense. Which is to be expected.

Comment: So the answer to the question " which subsets are nowhere dense " is **a proper closed set**. Am I right?

Comment: Closed *proper subset* would be the correct and unambiguous answer. An even more explicit answer would be $A$ such that $a\notin A$, since such $A$ must be closed, and this is a door topology: sets are either open or closed.

Comment: I understand ! Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of subsets $A$ of $X$:

$a \in A$, then $A$ is open by definition, and dense as all other non-empty open subsets also contain $a$ and so intersect $A$.

$a \notin A$, then $A$ is closed (as $X\setminus A$ then does contain $a$ so is open) and contains no non-empty open set (or it would also have contained $a$), so $\operatorname{int}(\overline{A}) = \operatorname{int}(A) = \emptyset$ and $A$ is nowhere dense.

So not every proper subset is nowhere dense, just all the non-open ones.

Note that this set is a so-called "door space": every subset is open or closed (or both). This is quite a rare property, really.